# Sticky tab bar with Fluent UI's Pivot

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

I am building a tabbed environment using Fluent UI's `Pivot` component. Some of the tabs (or `PivotItems` in Fluent UI parlance) are quite long and need to be scrollable. Is there a way of having the tab bar be sticky such that it stays on top of the frame and visible no matter where the user scrolls to on the tab?

Comment: If I understand well you need something like https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/abZRwZR If that's a case I'll explain my answer.

Comment: Hi Marko, this indeed looks like what I need. Could you add this as the answer with explanations? Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck! @foobar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get expected behavior you just need some `CSS`.

Set `height` of `body` and `html` to [100vh](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/), and `overflow: hidden` to avoid multiple scrollbars.

```
body, html {
  height: 100vh; /* Viewport height */
  overflow: hidden; /* To avoid multiple scrollbars */
}
```

As a working example I'm gonna use [Links of large tab style](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pivot). Content of every item renders inside `PivotItem Component`. So, you have to put some styles on it:

```
const pivotItemStyles = {
  height: 'calc(100vh - 44px)',
  overflow: 'auto',
}
```

`PivotTabs` by default uses `height: 44px` that's the reason why I put calculate inside height property. `overflow: auto` is to get scrollable content.
Reference: [Pivot.styles.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/c6ae2b350037deb4e0bea07cdbdfe2e93455f4b1/packages/react-tabs/src/components/Pivot/Pivot.styles.ts#L104)

[Codepen working solution](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/vYKVVQb)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Marko. It works and does the job for me. I think that ideally Fluent UI should expose a property that allows making the tab bar sticky to avoid having to rely on a hardcoded constant (`44px`) in the height property for the `PivotItem`s.